# Transition of electron from HOMO to LUMO?

Tags: electronic-configuration, molecular-orbital-theory

Molecules usually have certain number of (doubly) occupied molecular orbitals and an infinite number of unoccupied molecular orbitals but the probability of electron makes the orbitals shapes so, how LUMO (empty of electrons) orbitals exist despite no electron occupying it?

Also, when electron absorb sufficient energy will go excited from HOMO to LUMO, but is it allowed that the other electron still in HOMO will also go excited to LUMO leave HOMO without any electrons?

Comment: `the probability of electron makes the P orbitals so, how LUMO orbitals exist despite no electron making ` I don't quite understand what you mean here and also in the second question. Please clarify your question.

Comment: sorry, I donot know if my question clear know or not?

Comment: An empty LUMO does **not** exist in the same sense that atoms and things and buildings and Earth do. Until it receives an electron, it is more like an abstract idea.

Comment: Thanks, it seems clear know but what about the transition of electron , why always one electron not both travel from HOMO to LUMO?

Comment: Well, it is possible (though with low probability) for the two electrons to go up to some vacant orbitals; that would be called a _doubly excited state_.

Comment: Thanks for your short but valuable answers for me.

Comment: @IvanNeretin You should write an answer based on that.

Comment: @AhmedMohammed Lots of molecules have normally orbitals with 1 electron.